# How can I find the number of ships on a board, inspired by the game battleship, from a two dimensional array

Tags: c#, matrix, optimization, multidimensional-array

I need to calculate the number of ships from a given two dimensional array (an example input you can find below, however it can be any length two dimensions).
Ships are like you see presented as in a Battleship game and are clearly spaced apart with "0" between them. The Ships will not touch each other.
I need to write a console app in C# to solve this problem.

Destroyers represents 3 X "1" on board. (in any order in a closed cluster [like inside a 2X2 cluster], arranged horizontally or vertically but not straight diagonally)

Submarines represents 2 X "1" on board. (arranged horizontally or vertically but not diagonally)

Patrol boats represents 1 X "1" on board.

Sample input:

```
namespace Ships
{
  class Program
  {
    static int[,] ships = new int[4, 10] {
    { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, },
    { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, },
    { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
    { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, },
  };

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    int countDestroyers  = 0;
    int countSubmarines  = 0;
    int countPatrolBoats  = 0;

    // code write here

    Console.WriteLine(countDestroyers);
    Console.WriteLine(countSubmarines);
    Console.WriteLine(countPatrolBoats);
  
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
 }
}
```

Some clarifications. :)

The intention is to find a solution to find and classify the ships for this given valid "battleship" like scenario (so real battleship rules does not apply). The board array will consist of both 0's and 1's and every boat will be separated by at-least a 0 in the input. (So no need to check/validate if the inputs contains 111111).

Comment: Looks like a homework question. You want someone to write the code for you? This will not help you progressing in your studies. Hint: write the matrix on paper and think about how you would calculate the numbers yourself. Then translate to an algorithm.

Comment: You don't need a "matrix". *Jedi-Wave* You need "ship" objects with a position, orientation and length.

Comment: If the assignment is aiming for you doing "matrix" stuff, it's a bad one.

Comment: hint: sweep horizontally to identify the horizontal ships, then sweep vertically to find the vertical ships

Comment: good point @Fildor - my assignment indeed is to find the number of ships from this two dimensional array. I will remove the word matrix from the above. :)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Simplest approach: Start in the upper left corner of the board and iterate over the array until you find a `1`, ie you found a ship. Now check the surroundings of that ship if you find additional `1` in the neighborhood.  Replace all connected `1`by `0` (so you wouldn't count them again). Depending on the number of connected `1` count the respective type of ship. Once this is done, continue your search for the next `1`. Do this until you arrive in the lower right corner of your board.

Comment: So,  your assignment is to detect objects of length 2 or 3 that can be oriented horizontally or vertically in a 2D grid. Why teachers need to wrap this into a "game" is beyond me.

Comment: Do "ships" need to have one unit in between one another? If not: be aware of the possibility of singularities. (Situation where two solutions are equally possible)

Comment: @Fildor Why not? It helps understanding the assignment if you can connect it to something everybody knows ... Furthermore, I'm not even sure this is a "School" assignment. Looks more like hackerrank or similar ...

Comment: @derpirscher I may have phrased this a little too strict. I am all for _good_ analogies. This is not one.

Comment: ^^ because if you are not careful with your analogies you may introduce requirements or rules you didn't intend to which may be detrimental to finding a good solution.

Comment: this was not a homework question. :)

Comment: I didn't but as stated by several people above: in its current form, this is not a good question to be asked on this site. Maybe add an attempt you made but failed or narrow it down to a specific problem you have implementing a solution.

Comment: @Fildor Can you be more specific? I am not sure how I can rewrite this to be more specific. :)

Comment: Well, the question is asking for an algorithm. That's not the purpose of this site. We cannot possibly teach you how to find an algorithm. Maybe this specific algorithm but still, it would be off topic. But: if you have an attempt at implementing your own that doesn't work for some reason, we'd be glad to help you with that.

Comment: This is not a [Specific programming problems](https://stackoverflow.com/tour#:~:text=Specific%20programming%20problems), as you did not put any effort in trying to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Actually I did - like my current implementation is finding the Patrol Boats (which is easiest) since that only requires finding if the adjacent locations are 0.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need matrix calculations for this. The 2d array is merely a method to store the data.

You need to do two things:

1. Find any field that contains a piece of a ship.
2. Look in all directions up to the border of the board and find orthogonally adjacent "1"s, where counting the number of ones gives you information on what it is.

When programming, you typically want to have small methods that do "one thing".

So my tip would be to have one method that uses two nested for loops to iterate over the rows and columns, that looks for a "1". When it finds one, it calls a different method with the row and column indices.

That second method looks through the orthogonally adjacent cells, one direction at a time (down and left). This is trivially doable with the indices. Your size counter starts at 1, and if you find another 1 in any direction, you increment that counter and keep looking in that direction. As soon as you hit a 0 or the edge of the board, you can use the counter to determine the type of the ship.

The only two things that remain is a) to prevent the first method from finding the 1s of ships you already found. The easiest way would probably to temporarily change counted 1s into a different value, e.g. 2. And the other thing to worry about is how to store the information on the ships, but that could be a `record struct` with row+column indices, the ship type as enum, and a horizontal/vertical orientation enum.

Note: In your example, the input isn't unambiguous, because it has 3 1s in an L shape, which could be 2+1 or 1+2. If - as indicated by your code - you only want to count the ships, that edge case doesn't matter, because no matter which direction you check first, you will always count 1x a size of 2, and then 1x the remaining 1.

For an input like

```
1 1 1
1 0 0
```

however the solution isn't unambiguous, because it could be 2x2 or 1x3+1x1. For this case, the outcome would be determined by the direction you check for adjacent 1s first.

Comment: thanks for the comment - based on that I have added clarification that every boat will be separated by at-least a 0 in the input. (So no need to check/validate if the inputs contains 111111).

Comment: @Fildor, "Destroyers represents 3 X "1" on board. (in any order in a closed cluster [like inside a 2X2 cluster], arranged horizontally or vertically but not straight diagonally)" the 'L' shape is a Destroyer (3 x "1" inside a 2x2 cluster).

Comment: @LightningRider ah, didn't take the edit into account.